# Timeline goof in Charmed

Tags: charmed

In the Season 6 episode "Witchstock" of *Charmed*, the sisters travel back to 1968 to meet Grams as a young witch (and hippy). Their mother Patty is a little girl. But Prue was born in 1970, as her tombstone seen in episode 1 of Season 4 shows. Was there ever an explanation (in-universe or out-of-universe) for the discrepancy, or was it just a massive goof?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was one of many goofs in the show. Patty was actually born in 1950, so in 1968 she would have been 18, not a little girl. So not as much a timeline goof as a casting goof, they should have had a teenager in the part.

If you would like to check out all of the discrepancies, [this site](https://www.moviemistakes.com/tv3466/pageall) has a pretty good listing of them. (Just for reference, there are 7 continuity mistakes for Witchstock alone on that page.)